# HTTP request from Angular sent as OPTIONS instead of POST

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, cors

I'm trying to send some HTTP requests from my angular.js application to my server, but I need to solve some CORS errors.

The HTTP request is made using the following code:

```
functions.test = function(foo, bar) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: api_endpoint + 'test',
        headers: {
            'foo': 'value',
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
            bar:'value'
        }
    });
};
```

The first try ended up with some CORS errors. So I've added the following lines to my PHP script:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding, X-Auth-Token, content-type');
```

The first error is now eliminated.

Now the Chrome's developer console shows me the following errors:

> angular.js:12011 OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/test (anonymous
>   function)
>
> 423ef03a:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8000/test. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP
>   status code 400

and the network request looks like I expected (HTTP status `400` is also expected):

[image: network request]

I can't imagine how to solve the thing (and how to understand) why the request will send on localhost as `OPTIONS` and to remote servers as `POST`. Is there a solution how to fix this strange issue?

Comment: Try adding 'Accept': 'application/json', in the header

Comment: That OPTIONS is a preflight request, sent by the browser because there are custom headers set in your POST call ; it's normal.

I think the issue is with the content of these headers.

Comment: The problem is that the response to the preflight (`OPTIONS`) request is not success, i.e. HTTP 400. That why the real (following) request fails. You have to make sure the response to the preflight request is valid.

Comment: What do you mean by the HTTP status code `400` is expected?

Comment: The POST request appends a header named "foo" and that name isn't listed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers. Either add "foo" to that list or don't post with that header.

Comment: Did you solve it? If yes, it would be good if you could describe why your webserver or application has been returning HTTP 400 for the `OPTIONS` request and how did you fix it. You can for example create another answer for that.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### TL;DR answer

#### Explanation

The `OPTIONS` request is so called [**pre-flight request**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), which is part of [*Cross-origin resource sharing* (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Browsers use it to **check if a request is allowed from a particular domain** as follows:

1. The browser wants to send a request to a particular URL, let's say a `POST` request with the `application/json` content type
2. First, it sends the *pre-flight* `OPTIONS` request to the same URL
3. What follows depends on the *pre-flight* request's response HTTP status code:

   - If the server replies with a non-`2XX` status response, the browser won't send the actual request (because he knows now that it would be refused anyway)
   - If the server replies with a `HTTP 200 OK` (or any other `2XX`) response, the browser will send the actual request, `POST` in your case

#### Solution

So, in your case, the proper header is present, you just have to **make sure the *pre-flight* request's response HTTP status code is `200 OK` or some other successful one (`2XX`)**.

---

### Detailed Explanation

#### [Simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests)

Browsers **are not** sending the *pre-flight* requests in some cases, those are so-called *simple requests* and are used in the following conditions:

> - One of the allowed methods:
>   - `GET`
>   - `HEAD`
>   - `POST`

- Apart from the headers automatically set by the user agent (for example, Connection, User-Agent, etc.), the only headers which are allowed to be manually set are the following:

  - `Accept`
  - `Accept-Language`
  - `Content-Language`
  - `Content-Type` (but note the additional requirements below)
  - `DPR`
  - `Downlink`
  - `Save-Data`
  - `Viewport-Width`
  - `Width`
- The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:

  - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
  - `multipart/form-data`
  - `text/plain`
- No event listeners are registered on any `XMLHttpRequestUpload` object used in the request; these are accessed using the `XMLHttpRequest.upload` property.
- No `ReadableStream` object is used in the request.

Such requests are sent directly and the server simply successfully processes the request or replies with an error in case it didn't match the CORS rules. In any case, the response will contain the CORS headers `Access-Control-Allow-*`.

#### [Pre-flighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests)

Browsers **are** sending the *pre-flight* requests if the actual request doesn't meet the *simple request* conditions, the most usually:

- custom content types like `application/xml` or `application/json`, etc., are used
- the request method is other than `GET`, `HEAD` or `POST`
- the `POST` method is of an another content type than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain`

You need to **make sure that the response to the *pre-flight* request has the following attributes**:

- successful HTTP status code, i.e. `200 OK`
- header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (a wildcard `*` allows a request from any domain, you can use any specific domain to restrict the access here of course)

From the other side, the server may **refuse the CORS request** simply by sending a response to the *pre-flight* request with the following attributes:

- non-success HTTP code (i.e. other than `2XX`)
- success HTTP code (e.g. `200 OK`), but without any CORS header (i.e. `Access-Control-Allow-*`)

See the [documentation on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) or for example [HTML5Rocks' CORS tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) for details.

Comment: thanks for your clear description, solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a very similar problem writing an Angular 2 app - that uses a NODE server for the API.

Since I am developing on my local machine, I kept getting Cross Origin Header problems, when I would try to POST to the API from my Angular app.

Setting the Headers (in the node server) as below worked for GET requests, but my PUT requests kept posting empty objects to the database.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-
Encoding, X-Auth-Token, content-type');
```

After reading [Dawid Ferenczy's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497399/http-request-from-angular-will-send-with-method-options-instead-of-post#40497696), I realized that the PREFLIGHT request was sending blank data to my server, and that's why my DB entries were empty, so I added this line in the NODE JS server:

```
  if (req.method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.end();
    }
```

So now my server ignores the PREFLIGHT request, (and returns status 200, to let the browser know everything is groovy...) and that way, the real request can go through and I get real data posted to my DB!

Comment: Well, you're not ignoring the pre-flight request, you're properly replying to it. It's not a purpose of the pre-flight request to tranfer any data, it's purpose is just to check if the real request will be allowed from the current domain.

Answer (score 4):

Just put

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
header("HTTP/1.1 200 ");
exit;}
```

at the beginning of your serverside app and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

For spring boot application, to enable cors request, use `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)` on your respective controller.

[Refer this doc](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

Answer (score 1):

The best is to :

1. have proxy.conf.json set:

   ```json
   {
     "/api": {
       "target": "http://localhost:8080",
       "secure": false,
       "logLevel": "debug",
       "changeOrigin": true
     }
   }
   ```
2. And then to make sure that URL that you are using in angular to send a request is **relative** (`/api/something`) and not **absolute** (`localhost:8080/api/something`). Because in that case the proxy won't work.

Answer (score 0):

From Chrome **v79+**, OPTIONS Check(**pre-flight request**) will no longer appear in the network tab-[Source](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/chrome-79-doesnt-show-cors-preflight/)