# Http request working on ionic serve but doesn't work on "ionic cordova run android --device"

Tags: rest, http, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic native http to make server requests. The server is hosted on aws and the apis are up and running (verified by postman).

When i do ionic serve the requests go through and work but when i try to run it on device it doesnt work. On inspection i get "net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED" and post is sent as OPTIONS

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://18.220.143.133/api/login", ok: false, …}

already tried adding  to  config.xml

```
login(user: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
return this.httpClient.post('http://18.220.143.133/api/login', user, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
}).pipe(
  tap(async (res: AuthResponse) => {

    if (res.success == true) {

      await this.storage.set('user',res.user);

       await this.storage.set('ACCESS_TOKEN', res.token);
      this.authSubject.next(true);
    }

  })
);
```

}

I expect http requests to go through from mobile devices as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP request from angular will send with method OPTIONS instead of POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497399/http-request-from-angular-will-send-with-method-options-instead-of-post)

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me, until in the config.xml file I added:

```
<preference name = "android-targetSdkVersion" value = "27" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your CORS for the API call. [This](https://fdezromero.com/cors-errors-in-ionic-apps/) may help. Also, since you're using Angular HTTP requests, check here [HTTP request from angular will send with method OPTIONS instead of POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497399/http-request-from-angular-will-send-with-method-options-instead-of-post?rq=1).