# Despite have a function for CORS, Spring application is responding with 406

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Assume that `Project` is our POJO class. Following function provides to delete a row from database. It is successfully working with POSTMAN requests.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/project")
@CrossOrigin
public class ProjectController {

    private final ProjectServiceImpl projectServiceImpl;

    ------------
    @DeleteMapping
    @RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> deleteProject(@PathVariable Long id) {
        boolean result = projectServiceImpl.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
    ------------
}
```

But requests from Angular project are rejecting with 403 message. And following message is appearing in console screen.

[image: Angular error without pre-flight]

After some searches. I learned, the application have to answer `pre-flight` requests with 200. To provide this, following function was added to controller.

```
@GetMapping
@RequestMapping("/delete/{id:[0-9]+}")
public ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder retreive(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok();
}
```

I used regex for request mapping because without it Spring Framework throws `/project/delete/{id}` already mapped with another function. Angular get its 200OK for `pre-flight` request with this way. But the application response is 406 for delete operation. Angular is sending `http://localhost:8080/project/delete/2` url to the application. If I send same link without have a function for CORS. Row has id with 2 will delete successfully. Am I missing something?

[image: Console error despite have a CORS support]

Sources:

[Why Angular sending OPTIONS message before DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497399/http-request-from-angular-sent-as-options-instead-of-post)

[How to add CORS support to Spring Boot application](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

To implement server side proxy: proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/project/**": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

modified section in angular.json

```
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "issue-management:build",
        "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
      },
```

and Angular project started with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` but result didn't change. Plus, suggestions in [this](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) article applied, again result didn't change.

Comment: in angular.json what is the key name under projects?

Comment: `"issue-management": { ... }`

Comment: if you are still seeing the issue, it will help me to resolve the issue if you can upload a sample code in github

Comment: Thanks in advance [link](https://github.com/AbdulkerimFettahoglu/issue-management-kerim)

Comment: can you also upload angular too?

Comment: You can find in `src/webui`

Comment: BTW Angular side doesn't have proxy in github version.

Comment: here is the  [PR](https://github.com/AbdulkerimFettahoglu/issue-management-kerim/pull/2)

Comment: Thanks Pavan. Please add your main changes as comment and with explanation. I will accept it. I can do it myself if you want.

Comment: I already update `corsConfigurer `, I couldn't figure out my the proxy.conf.json is not working, I will look into it some other time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your applications are running on two different ports, that causing the CORS issue.

Add the proxy(file proxy.conf.json) in your Angular application.

```
{
    "/project/**": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

and run this `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Refference [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

---

Update:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
        }
    };
}
```

worked, For some reason Angular proxy is not working

Comment: With proxy, behavior didn't change. Still get same responses.

Comment: did you also added proxyConfig (point 3 ) to angular.json from angular doc

Comment: yes and run with ng serve not the command wrote in answer. Plus I tried [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d) but result didn't change.

Comment: Can you share the updated changes you made, and can you run the shared command and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring security use the following:

```html
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
            .cors(withDefaults())
            ...
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

See spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors

Global configuration:

```html
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${cors.origins.urls}")
    public String allowedOrigins;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins.split(","));

    }
}
```

Comment: No I'm not using Spring Security.

Comment: sorry, are you using or not using spring security?

Comment: can you add the origins parameter to the @CrossOrigin in ProjectController, for example:
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://localhost:4200/project:1")
(with the http it is removed in my comment)

Comment: I have added `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/project")` to my controller. POSTMAN requests working fine but Angular behaviour didn't change.

Comment: I just added the global configuration above, can you try with that? remove the local @CrossOrigin annotation and comment the retrieve method.

Comment: btw which version of spring are you using?

Comment: `@CrossOrigin` already top of class. As far as I understand you mean move the annotation from top of function to class. I'm trying all suggestions with `retreive` method and without it. Then I answer. BTW spring boot version is "2.2.4.RELEASE"