# Why is the LoginEndpoint called twice, when calling it in service and subcribing the observable?

Tags: angular, service, observable

I can't understand why my endpoint in the backend is addressed twice.
This is my code:

**HttpService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiMethod, AuthEndPoints } from '../conts';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  /**
   * This function is used to make api calls.
   * It takes an apiMethod name, the api url and for
   * post and put it takes also the data which should be
   * send
   *
   * @param api AuthEndPoints
   * @param method ApiMethod
   * @param data any
   */
  requestCall(method: ApiMethod, api: AuthEndPoints, data?: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log("HttpService")
    let response;
    switch (method) {
      case ApiMethod.GET:
        response = this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}${api}`).pipe(
          catchError(err => this.handleError(err, this))
        );
        break;
      case ApiMethod.POST:
        response = this.http.post(`${environment.baseUrl}${api}`, data).pipe(
          catchError(err => this.handleError(err, this))
        );
        break;
      case ApiMethod.PUT:
        response = this.http.put(`${environment.baseUrl}${api}`, data).pipe(
          catchError(err => this.handleError(err, this))
        );
        break;
      case ApiMethod.DELETE:
        response = this.http.delete(`${environment.baseUrl}${api}`).pipe(
          catchError(err => this.handleError(err, this))
        );
        break;
    }
    return response;
  }

  /**
   * This function is used to handle the error
   * which can occure from an api call
   *
   * @param error HttpErrorResponse
   */
  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse, self): any {
    // if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    //   console.error('An error occured:', error.error.message);
    // } else {
    //   this._error.whichError(error.status, error.message);
    //   return throwError({error: error.message, status: error.status});
    //}
  }

}
```

This function is called in the **authService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpService } from '../../core/services/http/http.service';
import { ApiMethod, AuthEndPoints } from '../../core/services/conts';
import { StorageService } from '../../core/services/storage/storage.service';

export interface LoginForm {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export interface User {
  name?: string;
  username?: string;
  email?: string;
  password?: string;
  passwordConfirm?: string;
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpService,
    private router: Router,
    private storage: StorageService
  ) { }
   

  login(loginForm: LoginForm) {
    console.log("Login - AuthService")
    this.subscription =  this.http.requestCall(ApiMethod.POST, 
   AuthEndPoints.LOGIN, loginForm).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("Login - Observable")
      this.storage.saveToken(JSON.stringify(res.auth_token));
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }, (error) => {console.log(error)})
  }
```

And the login function from the authService is called in the **loginComponent**:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../../service/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false; // implementieren

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initLoginForm();
  }

  /**
   * loginForm
   */
  initLoginForm(): void {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
        Validators.minLength(8)
      ]),
      password: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4)
      ])
    });
  }

  /**
   * onSubmit
   */
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
console.log("LoginComponent")
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value)
  }
}
```

**LogingComponentHtml:**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <h1 style="text-align: center !important; width: 100%">Login Page</h1>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="form-group">
          <mat-form-field>
            <label>
              <input formControlName="email" matInput placeholder="E-Mail">
            </label>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <mat-form-field>
            <label>
              <input formControlName="password" matInput placeholder="Password">
            </label>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" type="submit">Login</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I log the endpoints in the BackEnd. Therefore I can see that the endpoint is addressed 2 times.

[image]

But when I access the endpoint via Postman, the endpoint is only accessed once.

[image]

**Client-Side log:**
[image]

**Network-Tab:**
[image]

I thought maby it is because I have not unsubscribed the observable. So i tried the follwoing:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpService,
    private router: Router,
    private storage: StorageService
  ) { }

   subscription: Subscription



  login(loginForm: LoginForm) {
    this.subscription =  this.http.requestCall(ApiMethod.POST, AuthEndPoints.LOGIN, loginForm).subscribe(res => {
      this.storage.saveToken(JSON.stringify(res.auth_token));
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }, (error) => {console.log(error)})
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
```

But that does not change.

Do you have any ideas? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? Or has anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: I recommend adding logs on a client-side as well: 1. At the beginning of the **login** method (to ensure that it's called just once). 2. Inside the **subscribe** block (to understand, how many times it gets triggered). Share this info with us, please.

Comment: Please include `handleError` in your post. Nothing in the code shown should lead to repeated api calls. Also, you can use Networking Tools in the browser to see how may api calls were made

Comment: @AndrewAllen added the handle error function, but it is commented out. So not in Use at this point

Comment: Looks strange. Is anything interesting in the "network" tab? There is just one call, right? Would be great to take a look at that.

Comment: Yeah, strange. updated the question

Comment: Oh, that's a preflight request, read about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497399/http-request-from-angular-sent-as-options-instead-of-post

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents - you should never call subscribe in your service - use map instead