# 405 method not allowed error when making http post request from angular to web api

Tags: angular, webapi

I have an angular app with a .net core web-api as the back end.
the get request from the client works as expected and data from the server is fetched.

but when i try to post from the client to the server i get a 405 method not allowed error.

i have implemented the CORS middle ware found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844400/6617849) :

```
    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name");
    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");
```

**web-api controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PostsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Post>> Get()
    {
        return _repository.Get().ToList();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Post post)
    {
        if (post == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        _repository.Add(post);
        _repository.Save();
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetPostById", new { ID = post.Id }, post);
    }
}
```

**Post model on server**

```
   public class Post 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  apiUrl = 'http://localhost:33633/api/posts';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

onCreatePost(postData: { title: string; content: string }) {

this.http.post(this.apiUrl, postData).subscribe(responseData =>
{
  console.log(responseData);
})
}
  onFetchPosts() {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl).subscribe(responseData =>
    {
      console.log(responseData);
    })
  }
```

**console error when trying to post to server:**
[image]

what could be the reason for this error?

**---Edit - found a solution---**
in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21458845/6617849)

i added a base controller with the method

```
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
  return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```

and now it works.

Comment: Did you allow CORS in your backend service ?

Comment: yes - as i mentioned the link to the CORS middleware i am using in my backend.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the HTTP verb `OPTIONS` is not supported by the URL you are calling.

Such requests are fired automatically even though you only fire `POST` or `GET` from your code. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/40497696/5389127.

You have to allow `OPTIONS` requests on your backend.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong here, but for my understanding if the options request fails in angular - the browser will not send the post request to the server. the CORS on the server allows all these methods: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS. how can i allow the OPTIONS http verb on the web api controller?

Comment: You're right, if the `OPTIONS` request does not succeed, no other requests will be made. I'll edit my answer. How to allow OPTIONS on your backend is entirely dependent on your backend tech/framework. I'd suggest posting another question dedicated to your backend.

Comment: thank you for the related informative answer, I have edited my post with the solution that I found in another stack overflow answer.